# How to get message_id in the response object when using AWS SES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, email, actionmailer

I want to get the actual `MESSAGE-ID` of the email sent to the user when I send the mail from my app.

gems I am using

```
 gem 'aws-sdk`
 gem 'mail'
```

config looks like this

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {:xx => xx,:return_response => true}
```

when I do

```
response = MyMailer.some_mail.deliver_now
```

currently `response.message` returns the `Net::SMTP::Response` object which looks like this

`#<Net::SMTP::Response:0x00YY @status="250", @string="250 Ok XX-XX-XX\n">`
where `XX-XX-XX` is the part of the actual message_id but what I need is the exact message_id set by SES.

Is there any way of achieving it?

Comment: I am not sure about SES but with other services like mailchimp etc you can always pass a `custom args` while sending an email. Of course you need to setup a webhook to receive updates from them and with every update they would send you the respective `arg` attached to a mail. assuming you are trying to track email events.

Comment: When you say the "actual" message-id, you are referring to the actual message-id as seen... *where?* The `Message-Id:` in the headers of the actual email that's being delivered?

Comment: yes, by actual message-id I mean the message-id of the email received by the user.

Comment: @sarthakagarwal did you find any workaround here? I can see a different message-id being sent by the gem but eventually the "Show Original" has a different message-id altogether